# xalan and custom function for xslt

Tags: xslt, xalan, ikvm

I'm using Apache FOP with the IKVM from my c# code. I generate the pdf by using the xslt stylesheet to get the result as xsl fo. I have one problem, that is usingthe custom functions. 
My stylesheet declaration:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                 xmlns:cal="xalan://m.test"
              extension-element-prefixes="cal"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance http://www.xmlblueprint.com/documents/fop.xsd">
```

The custom function:

```
namespace m
{
    public class test
    {
        public static string zzz(ExpressionContext x, object d)
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

And calling this from the xslt:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="cal:zzz(1)"/>
```

Code to compile it:

```
 FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
            fopFactory.ignoreNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            fopFactory.setUserConfig(new File("fop.xconf"));

            OutputStream o = new DotNetOutputMemoryStream();

            try
            {
                Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop("application/pdf", o);

                TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

                Source xsltSrc = new StreamSource(new File("data.xsl"));
                Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsltSrc);

                var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("data.xml"); //"HR_CV.fo");
                var stream = new DotNetInputMemoryStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes));

                Source src = new StreamSource(stream);

                Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

                transformer.transform(src, res);
            }
            finally
            {
                o.close();
            }
```

Exception I got is:
java.lang.NoSychMethodExtension: For extension function, could not find method org.apache.xml.utils.NodeVector.zzz([ExpressionContext,])

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You're calling the `zzz` function with a single argument (1). But your function expects two arguments. If you provide both arguments, chances are it will work just fine.